# Next.Js - Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cancel rendering route

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, next.js13

I am trying to create basic authentication and route protection for pages in Next.Js, before I start connecting them to the backend (Express.Js).

However I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cancel rendering route
```

[image]

I have 2 layouts, Main Layout, which renders the PageHeader, SideBar and the content of the page, and Login layout, which only renders PageHeader and Login Form.

It tells me that the problem is in useUserSession.tsx, but I have no idea what is the error.

My useUserSession.tsx looks like this:

```
    import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import { useCallback, useState } from "react"


const useUserSession = () => {

    const[username, setUsername] = useState<any>()
    const[userLoggedIn, setUserLoggedIn] = useState<any>()
    const router = useRouter();

    const login = useCallback(() => {

        setUsername('Admin');
        setUserLoggedIn(true);
        router.push("/")

    }, [])

    const loggout = useCallback(() => {
        setUsername('');
        setUserLoggedIn(false);
        router.push("/login")
    }, [])

    return {username, userLoggedIn, login, loggout }
}

export default useUserSession
```

And my userSession looks like this:

```
    import React, { createContext } from 'react'

const userSession = createContext({
    isLoggedIn: false,
    username: String,


    login: () => {

    },

    loggout: () => {

    }
})


export default userSession;
```

My _app.tsx

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {

    const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page)

    const { username, userLoggedIn ,login, loggout } = useUserSession();

    return getLayout(    
        <userSession.Provider value={{isLoggedIn: userLoggedIn, username, login: login, loggout}} >

            <Component {...pageProps} />

        </userSession.Provider>

    )
}
```

My MainLayout.tsx

```
    function MainLayout({children} : {children: ReactNode}) {

    const { username, userLoggedIn ,login, loggout } = useUserSession();

    return (
        <userSession.Provider value={{isLoggedIn: userLoggedIn, username, login: login, loggout}} >
            <PageHeader/>
            <UserSideBar/>
            <div className="pageContent">
                {children}
            </div>
        </userSession.Provider >

    )
}

export default MainLayout
```

My LoginLayout.tsx

```
function LoginRegisterLayout({children} : {children: ReactNode}) {
    const { username, userLoggedIn ,login, loggout } = useUserSession();

    return (
        <userSession.Provider  value={{isLoggedIn: userLoggedIn, username, login: login, loggout}} >
            <PageHeader/>
            {children}
        </userSession.Provider>

    )
}

export default LoginRegisterLayout
```

And this is my Login.tsx

```
const Login: PageWithLayout = () =>{

    const errorMessagesClass = `${styles.disabled}`;
    const userSessionData = useContext(userSession);



    return (
        <div className={styles.LoginPage}>
            <div className={styles.LoginForm}>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form>
                    <div className={styles.LoginFormInputs}>
                        <div>
                            <label htmlFor='usernameInput'>Username or Email: </label>
                            <input type={'text'} id='usernameInput'></input>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label htmlFor='passwordInput'>Password: </label>
                            <input type={'password'} id='passwordInput'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={`${styles.ErrorMessages} ${errorMessagesClass}`}>
                        
                    </div>
                    <button type='submit' >Login in to your account</button>
                    <Link href="#" onClick={userSessionData.login}>login</Link>
                </form>
                <p className={styles.FormFooter}>Don&apos;t have a profile ? 
                    <Link href='/register'>Create one now
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-user-plus"></i>
                    </Link>
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

Login.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement){
    return(
        <LoginRegisterLayout>
            {page}
        </LoginRegisterLayout>
    )
}


export default Login
```

And this is my Index.tsx that the user can visit only when he has logged in.

```
const Home: PageWithLayout = () => {

    const userSessionData = useContext(userSession);
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!userSessionData.isLoggedIn){
            router.push("/login");
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Kiwi | Home page</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>

            <div className={styles.NewPostContainer} id="NewPostContainer">
                <div className={styles.NewPostFormContainer} id="textAreaContainer">
                    <Image src='/images/user_icon.png' width="512" height="512" alt='User profile image'/>
                    <textarea id='newPostForm' onChange={changeFormHeight}/>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.NewPostToolbar}>
                    <p></p>
                    <button>Post</button>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div className='ContentContainer'>
                  
                <Post/>
                    
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

Home.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement){
    return(
        <MainLayout>
            {page}
        </MainLayout>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1):

You called `router.push` on a `Link` tag without preventing its event and it made this error.

For solution add `e.preventDefault()` to your `Link` tag  like this:

```
<Link href="#" onClick={(e)=> {
e.preventDefault();
userSessionData.login();
}>login</Link>
```